# VBA multiple IF values

Tags: vba, excel

The below code works and changes the offset cells when north is entered, i would like to also have it change if its south, west or east but i can seem to find a way to add this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range


Set KeyCells = Range("A7:A26")
Set rng = Range("A7:A26")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If cell.Value = "North" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            cell.Offset(0, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End If
    Next

   End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to use the same colour or different colours for each direction??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot. Just update the color assignments as needed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

Set KeyCells = Range("A7:A26")
Set rng = Range("A7:A26")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
   Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If cell.Value = "North" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            cell.Offset(0, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        ElseIf cell.Value = "South" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            cell.Offset(0, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ElseIf cell.Value = "East" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            cell.Offset(0, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        ElseIf cell.Value = "West" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
            cell.Offset(0, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
        End If
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a Select Case instead of If statements for this.

```
For Each cell In Rng.Cells
    Select Case cell.Value
        Case "North"
            Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        Case "South"
            Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 155, 0)
        Case "East"
            Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 55, 0)
        Case "West"
            Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: Never used Select Case before, I will have a look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Select Case is often ignored by new programmers, but it can make code easier to follow and understand.  Enjoy!

Comment: [Select...Case Statement (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
 If cell.Value = "North" Or cell.Value = "South" Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        cell.Offset(0, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
 End If
```

or:

```
 If cell.Value = "North" Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        cell.Offset(0, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
 ElseIf cell.Value = "South"
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        cell.Offset(0, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
 End If
```